# how to change keras backend in windows?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In ubuntu I can find

```
~/.keras/keras.json
```

and change the backend
but in windows, I can not find this file. How can I  change keras backend in windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can create keras.json in the same way as on linux. The '`backend`' key will have either '`tensorflow`' or '`theano`'. Place the file in `%USERPROFILE%/.keras`